# Need to pass data to model

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

```
            <div class="col-lg-8"> <!-- Right side for cards -->
                    <div class="tab-content" id="projectsTabsContent">
                        @foreach ($wings as $wing)
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="wing-{{ $wing->wing }}" role="tabpanel"
                                aria-labelledby="wing-{{ $wing->wing }}-tab">
                                <div class="row">
                                    @foreach ($projects as $project)
                                        @if ($project->wing === $wing->wing && $project->status === 'ongoing')
                                            <div class="blog-card row" style="border-radius: 10px">
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <h6 style="color: black">{{ $project->project_name }}</h6>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-2 mt-2 mt-sm-0 text-sm-right">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#projectDetailsModal" data-description="{{ $project->description }}" style="border-radius: 30px">Read More</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>   
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
@endsection
<div class="modal fade" id="projectDetailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="projectDetailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="projectDetailsModalLabel">Project Details</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- This is where the project description will be displayed -->
                <p id="projectDescription"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // Assuming jQuery is already included in your project
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Listen for a click event on buttons that have the data-toggle="modal"
    $(document).on('click', 'button[data-toggle="modal"]', function() {
        // Retrieve the description from the button's data-description attribute
        var description = $(this).data('description');
        
        // Update the modal's body with the project description
        $('#projectDescription').text(description);
    });
});
```

I tried to pass the project description value for showing on model when click read more button.it doesn't work. tried to pass using the button.but not work.data came from the database via controller.i need to show them on frontend.i tried various ways.help me!

Comment: btw, it is a modal, not a model